# jQuery file upload with post

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would ask, is there any way to redirect to other page with post data after file upload successfully?
Here is my code:

```
    $(function() {
var bar = $('#bar');
    var percent = $('#percent');
 var status = $('#status');
    $('form').ajaxForm({

        beforeSend: function() {
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
               location.href='upload.php'; //here i need to redirect to selected page with post request
        }
    });});
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to post and update the html manually.
Probably something like this.

```
complete: function(data){
    $.post('upload.php', function( data ) {
        $('body').html(data)
        window.history.pushState({"html": $('html').html() ,"pageTitle": 'title'}, "", 'upload.php');
    });
}
```

Comment: loading page content, but not getting it with post.

Comment: no, it doesn't sending post data. I receiving only a page without set data.